# Which javascript/flash library does deviantart use to handle file uploads?

Tags: javascript, flash, frontend, image-uploading, asyncfileupload

Not only you can see a progress bar, but it also shows you a small thumbnail of the image while you are uploading it.

They seem to reference a 'deck_uploader' library, but I couldn't find it on google.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you mention "deck_uploader" actually refers to the uploading of a deck of photos - an operation highly specific to deviantArt - so the rest of the upload cod might be custom made for them too.

On the other hand I don't know why you would need that information, but I suppose you want to copy the code/functionality to another site. My advice is to never copy code or design from someone else - it a lot of work and you end up with hard to support spaghetti code that you understand in half.

Once you've set up your requirements look for an open source (javascript) framework to handle uploads. jQuery upload could be a candidate. http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload.

Also, another idea might be to use the HTML5 specification, which allows uploading multiple files like so:

```
<form action='#' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <input name='uploads[]' type=file>
  <input name='uploads[]' type=file>
  <input name='uploads[]' type=file>
  <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: Well I looked for a library like this for decades, and I just found it somewhere else, some minutes ago.